# itextsharp columntext borders are not border of page

Tags: c#, itext

I'm writing a document in iText composite mode, and it displays fine when my columntext widths are wider than the page.

example:

```
float[][] width =
            {
                new[] {_document.Left, _document.Right},
                new[] {_document.Left, _document.Right}
            };
```

This causes my table to be misaligned with the header above it.

However, if I use:

```
float[][] width =
                {
                new[] {_document.Left-67, _document.Right+55},
                new[] {_document.Left-67, _document.Right+55}
                };
```

Then the table is aligned with its header properly.
When the class opens I set up the document with the following:

```
private void SetupDocument()
{
   _document.SetMargins(5f, 5f, 5f, 5f);
   _document.SetMarginMirroring(true);
   _document.Open();
}
```

and the document type is 'letter' so the width is 612.
So why would the column text be misaligned when using the documents left and right margins, but be correct when the left margin is at -62 and the right margin is at 662?

EDIT: the section of the method that uses the widths, and prints the data. _verticalAlign is 510 because I have some manually formatted fields above
I used the general idea from:http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/book/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter04/ColumnTable.cs

```
            column.AddElement(LocationNotes(fpoData));

            int count = 0;
            int status = 0;
            while (ColumnText.HasMoreText(status))
            {
                if (count == 0)
                {
                    column.SetSimpleColumn(
                        width[count][0],_document.Bottom,
                        width[count][1],_verticalAlign
                    );
                    count++;
                }
                else if (count > 0)
                {
                    _verticalAlign = 760;
                    _document.NewPage();
                    count = 0;
                    CreateFooter(fpoData);
                    column.SetSimpleColumn(
                            width[count][0], _document.Bottom,
                            width[count][1], _verticalAlign
                    );
                }
                status = column.Go();
            }
```

Comment: I've read your question three times and I don't understand the problem. Could you throw in some more code? I have no idea how you are using the two-dimensional `width` array.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I've updated with where the `width` is used. There isn't anything else below the while loop.

Comment: Why do you need a two-dimensional array? `widht[0][0]` equals `width[1][0]` and `width[1][0]` equals `width[1][0]`. Why are you using margin mirroring when your left margin is identical to your right margin? How are you creating your `Document` and why don't you define your margins in the `Document` constructor (instead of using a `SetupDocument()` method)? I suggest that you first clean up your code and then clean up your question. Right now, I don't see any way I could answer your question as I can't reproduce the problem.